# XPath multiple contains to verify innerText in all subnodes

Tags: c#, html, xml, xpath

I have a question regarding Xpath based on this html:

```
<p>Foo<br>Bar<br></p>
```

Is there a way to combine a expression to verify that first textnode contains Foo and next contains Bar?

The code i have right now is splitted like this:

```
var node = DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode($"//*[text()[contains(.,'Foo')]]");
var node1 = DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode($"//*[text()[contains(.,'Bar')]]");

node.Should().NotBeNull();
node1.Should().NotBeNull();
```

Comment: that is not XML, because the `br` tags aren't properly closed. That looks HTML.

Comment: If that's your actual code, it's hard to read and maintain. Why not just use C# and leverage Linq To XML via `Enumerable.SkipWhile` and `Enumerable.TakeWhile`.

Comment: Sorry @MarioVernari i edited the question, it is html not xml.

Comment: @AluanHaddad i'm writing some tests for tokenizing a email template. I have to determine that the tokens is replaced with the actual values before the mail is sent to subscribers.

Answer (score 0):

It depends a bit on the API you use, `SelectSingleNode` can return a node or null, `SelectNodes` returns an `XmlNodeList`, meanwhile there is also XPathNavigator.Evaluate which can return a boolean value so you could use e.g. `(bool)DocumentNode.CreateNavigator().Evaluate("contains(//p/text()[1], 'Foo') and contains(//p/text()[2], 'Bar')")`, for instance with the current version of HtmlAgilityPack the code

```
        string html = @"<p>Foo<br>Bar<br></p>";

        HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
        doc.LoadHtml(html);

        bool result = (bool)doc.CreateNavigator().Evaluate("contains(//p/text()[1], 'Foo') and contains(//p/text()[2], 'Bar')");

        Console.WriteLine(result);
```

outputs True.

Comment: aa okay. In this case i'd like to verify that one single htmlnode, the <p></p>, contains 2 or more subexpressions separated by <br>. Im looking for something like: `DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode($"//*[text()[contains(.,'Foo')]][contains(.,'Bar')]]")`

Comment: I will try your XpathNavigator solution, thank you :)

Comment: You should be able to use e.g. `DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode($"//*[text()[contains(.,'Foo')] and text()[contains(.,'Bar')]]")` or `DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode($"//*[text()[contains(.,'Foo')]][text()[contains(.,'Bar')]]")`

Comment: @MartinHonnen he cannot use any Xml*/Xpath* API because the source document is not XML. The parser would throw. Either he uses HTML API (script or some 3rd party lib) or guarantees an XML (e.g. XHTML).

Comment: With the input being HTML there might nevertheless be an API allowing the use of XPathNavigator on a tree created by an HTML parser, the current version of HTMLAgilityPack only seems to have `SelectNodes` and `SelectSingleNode` https://html-agility-pack.net/select-single-node, I don't remember for sure whether it at some point supported `CreateXPathNavigator` and therefore e.g. `Evaluate` as well. But I don't see why you claim that XPath APIs don't work with HTML, in the browser as well as with (non Microsoft) APIs many libraries allow using XPath against a DOM or tree parsed from HTML.

Comment: @MartinHonnen I don't claim anything, read the definition: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath
By the way, the HTML DOM trasversal is most of the times made through the CSS selectors, not XPath: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.php